# Inserting braces in a brace

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting, display-math-mode

I don’t know how can I ensert the right braces using latex...

Any help is appreciated...

[image]

Comment: That seems to be a question for [tex.se], rather than this meta.

Comment: A fairly tedious way to do it would be using nested "array" expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach, using the `cases` environment for the left side brace and some `array` environments to group and brace on the right hand side:

$$ \begin{cases}
  \left. \begin{array}{l}
\frac{dG(t)}{dt} = G_{in} - \sigma_2 G - a\left(c+ \frac{mI}{n+I} \right)G + b \\
\frac{dI(t)}{dt} = \frac{\sigma_1 G^2}{\alpha_1^2 + G^2} - d_i I(t) \end{array}
  \right\} & , \;\;\; G\lt L_G \text{ or } I\gt I_C, \\
  \left. \begin{array}{l}
G(t^+) = G(t) \\
I(t^+) = I(t) + \sigma \end{array}
  \right\} & , \;\;\; G = L_G \text{ and } I\le I_C, \end{cases} $$

Note that the `cases` environment itself could be similarly replaced by using an `array` environment plus adaptive bracing.  The idea was suggested in [this note about the "cases" package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cases/cases.pdf).

Comment: Which is more aesthetically pleasing than the screenshot, I'd say.

Comment: This is nice. The real challenge would be to also have all four of those first equality signs (on each line) perfectly aligned. I guess that's a question for the TeXperts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think you are right about the difficulty of aligning the equations across the `cases` boundaries.  A naive use of the `align*` environment apparently produces an error message about nested equation structures.

Comment: or just use {case1\\case2}\raise{-12px}{\bigg\}} doing it for both.

Comment: example:$$\left\{{\left.{case1\\[6px]case2} \right\}\\[6px]\left.{case3\\[6px]case4}\right\}}\right.$$ okay maybe a case environment would be better